# How can I make the Domain Controller the client's default gateway?

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2016, dhcp-server, windows-sbs-2008

I'm migrating from a SBS 2008 DC to a Windows Server 2016 DC. On the SBS DC, DHCP is set up and I've migrated this successfully to Server 2016. The PC's in the office use the SBS DC as their default gateway. When I change the default gateway on any of the PC's to new DC's IP they lose internet connection. Why is the new DC not able to be a default gateway?

Note: The SBS server has AD, DNS and DHCP. I've replicated all this across to the new DC.

Comment: Why the DC act as a gateway, you don't use a router ? as for me it mean your SBS is possibly multhomed, which is not a good setup with a DC. As you are in project's mode, it's the good time to do it correctly.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Doesn't the DC need to be the default gateway to handle DHCP requests? I don't want the router to handle DHCP requests.

Comment: DHCP request got nothing to do with the default gateway. The computer do a broadcast to send the DHCP packet, while the default gateway is used when the computer want to talk outside the LAN, while he already have a DHCP lease

Comment: @yagmoth555 - Ok thank you. I was getting a bit confused. Not sure why the current DC is the default gateway when we have a router.

Answer (score 0):

SBS was designed to be a single do it all solution for small businesses (even email server with Exchange in the earlier versions) and as such it allows you to implement connection sharing by making it multi homed with two NICs (one internal and one external), and not sure but I believed it used ISA server of Microsoft forefront or something like that to do proxing, content filtering and kind of firewalling internal PC's from the Internet.

Server 2016 by itself does not do that and unless you are using SBS it is never a good idea to have a multi-homed domain controller, this can give you a lot of headaches... If you have such a setup you'll need to get a device that replaces the old SBS for the network connection sharing  function, like a firewall / router (you may already have one), then you should point the gateway on your clients to your Firewall's internal IP.